# Eclipse Kepler RCP Main Toolbar Actions

Tags: eclipse-rcp, action, toolbar, eclipse-kepler, workbench

Google **is** my best friend, but the information I'm getting is too scattered and very unclear. There isn't a concise tutorial describing my needs.

I want to add actions to my RCP app's main toolbar, but I need every way of doing this explained thoroughly. But since this is StackOverflow, I will write down the questions off the top of my head, and hope the answers will do.

- Which is the **new** and **old** way of adding actions? Via `ActionBarAdvisor` or via `plugin.xml`?
- Can actions be added to the main toolbar **ONLY** using `plugin.xml`?
- How many steps are there to add an action via extensions? (`handlers`, `commands`, `menuContribution`, etc.)
- Which is the best parent for an action implementation? `org.eclipse.jface.action.Action`? `org.eclipse.ui.menus.WorkbenchWindowControlContribution`? Or even `org.eclipse.ui.commands.AbstractHandler`?
- What about workbench-specific actions (**Save**, **Undo**, **Redo** etc.)? How are these added?
- In Eclipse Kepler IDE, the coolbar looks beautiful. You can even move toolbars around. How's that implemented? Couldn't find out not even with Plug-in Spy.
- Since I have several `Perspective`s, each will come with its own contribution on the main toolbar. Does that mean I'm obliged to use `plugin.xml` extensions everywhere?

---

**TL;DR**: Workbench coolbar actions including **Save** and actions from other `Perspective`s. How? (`actionSets` extensions == deprecated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The really new way is to use a pure e4 RCP which uses the new application model with commands and handlers! (but e4 doesn't support a lot of existing code). In e4 menus and toolbars are defined in the application model. Commands and handlers are used in a similar way to traditional code (but handlers are implemented differently).

For Eclipse 3 style as you have found there is a jumble or ways of doing things. Eclipse 4.3 does deprecate some of the oldest (and this is now flagged in the `plugin.xml`).

If you are writing a RCP which uses its own `ActionBarAdvisor` then you can define your tool bar items there. Or you can define them in the `plugin.xml` for individual plugins. Both methods are fine. Eclipse itself defines core actions in the advisor with add on plugins defining more in their plugin.xmls.

Actions such as **Save** which need to be handled by multiple parts (such as editors) should be created in the advisor and use `RetargetAction`. This allows each individual part to hook up its own action with the globally defined action. This can also be done with `commands` and multiple `handlers` which are closer to the e4 style.

`org.eclipse.ui.menus` is now the main extension point for contributing to menus and toolbars (ignoring all the deprecated parts). This does pretty much force you to use `commands` and `handlers`.

The Eclipse action bar advisor is `org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.WorkbenchActionBuilder` which may help although it is big.

I think the coolbar in Kepler is constructed using the new e4 application model with styling using some tricky CSS.

Comment: Migrating the whole app to pure e4 isn't worth it, as it would take a bit of time. Currently it uses the deprecated `actionSets`, `viewActions`, and other old stuff, thus resulting in really annoying visual bugs on Windows especially (a little less on OSX). What is your take on the `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension? Is it a convenient replacement for the above? Given your e4 experience.

Comment: Migrating to pure e4 is hard especially if you use any `org.eclipse.ui.xx` plugins or anything relying on `IWorkbench`. Only really useful for a new application (or like me you have a lot of time available).

Comment: Saved by you yet again. :-) Thanks.