# RCP Start the product with Clear Workspace

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

So I've come across this weird bug in RCP Apps.

I've created a new RCP App with the Mail Template. I've added a new `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension with a `menuContribution` with `locationURI:toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar`. To that, I've added a command with a little icon.

Now, if I start the app without `Clear Workspace` in the Debug Configurations, my action appears AFTER the Quick Access text widget. Not only that, but a few other bugs come along (e.g. views aren't closing, too many views are opening at once). This is not a one-time thing, i.e. I have to start the app with `Clear Workspace` each time.

This method of adding actions on the `coolBar` is non-deprecated. Why does it behave like a spoiled brat?

**Without Clear Workspace:**
[image]

**With Clear Workspace:**
[image]

Comment: Is this a one time thing or do you have to do it every time?

Comment: @Baz Everytime, unfortunately.

Comment: @Baz Frankly I'm really curious how Eclipse's actions are put there in the coolbar, with all the movable toolbars. Somebody explained that to me once, but I swear I don't remember the explanation.

Comment: The core actions are added in `WorkbenchActionBuilder` (a subclass of `ActionBarAdvisor`).

Comment: @greg-449 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19594890/eclipse-kepler-rcp-main-toolbar-actions Oh right, that was you. Anyway, this particular question is part of another scope.

Comment: There is a long discussion of the Eclipse forums about this [here](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/366870/) with a bug filed as a result [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=422651)

Comment: @greg-449 Excellent. Care to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a long discussion on the Eclipse forums about this [here](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/366870/) with a bug filed as a result [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=422651).

The bug is not scheduled to be fixed until Eclipse 4.4M5 but using one of the workarounds to remove the Quick Access control discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549283/remove-quick-access-entry-in-eclipse-juno) should help.

Comment: My research skills have failed me.